# How to use yii 2.0 Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, yii2

I'm using yii 2.0 framework and I would like to use Bootstrap carousel.

I know that there is the documentation but can someone explain to me what I have to do first? I have defined new action in controller and new view just like the documentation below. What should I edit?

siteController

```
public function actionHello($message = "Hello"){
    return $this->render('say', ['message' => $message]);
}
```

say.php view

```
<?php 

use yii\helpers\Html;

?>
```

Comment: Add the sample code from this link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
to your view page and check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By `Yii 2.0` bootstrap widget, there is nothing to do much and it is quite easy. I your view you can do it like below:

```
$images=['<img src="/path/to/file1"/>','<img src="/path/to/file2"/>','<img src="/path/to/file3"/>'];
echo yii\bootstrap\Carousel::widget(['items'=>$images]);
```

All done.

You can pass image files from your controller like below:

```
//getting all images
$images=['<img src="/path/to/file1"/>','<img src="/path/to/file2"/>','<img src="/path/to/file3"/>'];    
return $this->render('say',['message'=>$message,'images'=>$images]);
```

Then in view:

```
echo yii\bootstrap\Carousel::widget(['items'=>$images]);
```

You can read the official document to get it more clear and have more customization with it.

[Class yii\bootstrap\Carousel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-carousel.html)